# How can I set the "Google Authenticator" code to 4 digits instead of 6 digits?

Tags: google-authenticator

I can generate code with Google Authenticator. But it generates a 6 digits code by default. What is the way to set it as 4 digits?

I tried this but didn't get the result I expected.

`var generatedCode = $"otpauth://totp/{host}:{email}?secret={secretKey}&issuer={host}&digits=4";`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [open source version of the Google Authenticator Android app](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-android), there is no support for any number of digits other than 6. The `parseSecret` method which interprets otpauth URIs never reads the `digits` query para, only `secret` and `issuer`. And the `OtpProvider` class has

```
private static final int PIN_LENGTH = 6; // HOTP or TOTP
```

which is passed into the `PasscodeGenerator` — it's a baked-in constant, not user-controlled.

Comment: [Other implementations](https://github.com/freeotp/freeotp-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/fedorahosted/freeotp/Token.java) offer support for digits other than six. Perhaps a fork could be created specifically to support four. I don't believe four is in the reference RFC however.